# Content Blocks Disappearing from email

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

Our users are experiencing issues when adding content to email. Content appears as expected, but after navigating away from email (i.e., back to content builder main page or to preview & test) content blocks are disappearing entirely from the email. Issue seemed to begin after major update 2 weeks ago.

Sounds familiar? Is anyone having similar issues?

Comment: Assuming you're not using the browser back navigation buttons and clicking 'save' or 'save and exit' before leaving.   I would raise a ticket with support to see if it's a known issue on your SFMC stack.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the email is not saving in Content Builder. Click “Save” before moving on to Preview.